# Создать ссылки для оплаты под каждого клиента

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Asp.net mvc приложение. Существует в БД таблица (1), которая содержит различные параметры, в разрезе лицевых счетов по клиентам. Нужно пройтись по данной таблице и сформировать уникальную ссылки для каждого клиента, для последующей визуализации. Сформированные ссылки будут отправляться клиентам. Клиент переходит по ссылке, открывается сайт и должен увидеть свои данные (из 1).

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался или может где описано? Как такое можно сделать? желательно получить ссылку не в таком формате "mysite/client/1/1099....", чтобы клиенты не видели чужие данные.

Comment: "не в таком формате" - а в каком?

Comment: в виде хеша (или чего еще)...не хочу показывать весь "путь". Так как при открытии ссылки клиентом, необходимо ссылку разобрать, обратиться к базе и показать нужные данные

Comment: Пройтись по таблице и сформировать ссылки очень просто, поэтому подозреваю что вопрос не в этом. Может быть вы имели в виду что хотите подсказку как такие ссылки потом обработать когда пользователь по ним перейдет и выдать запрошенные данные?

Comment: Да, в принципе, интересует полностью вопрос. К примеру, клиент видет какую либо свою информацию. Допустим на данный момент http://mysite.ru/client/show/12/123, мне нужно закодировать допустим таким образом http://mysite.ru/gdjsbwjajw425@4hdjsjana

Comment: А затем все это расшифровать? Чтобы понятно было маршрутизации